# Show that each connected simple graph of $ n $ vertices is isomorphic to a subgraph of $ K_n $.

Tags: graph-theory

Show that each connected simple graph of $ n $ vertices is isomorphic to a subgraph of $ K_n $.

Attempt: Let $ G $ be the graph with set of vertices $ V (G) = \{v_1, \: v_2, \: \ldots, \: v_n \} $. Let $ V (K_n) = \{u_1, \: u_2, \: \ldots, \: u_n \} $ be the set of vertices of $ K_n $. We construct the subgraph $ H \subseteq K_n $ such that $ u_iu_j \in A (H) $ if and only if $ v_iv_j \in A (G) $. Note that $ H $ is an isomorphism of $ G $.

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Is what I did right? Is there something I am missing to consider?